# Update custom hook's variable after initial call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a custom fetch hook called useFetch() and initialled it in my App.js component, to render a list of movies when the web app loads up the page.
I am trying to load up a different list of movies based of on the user's search (name of the movie). but don't know if I am to update the data variable or call the useFetch again with a different variable.

```
 ....
const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState('morbius');
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

const {data, loading } = useFetch(`api-endpoint.com/apikey/${searchString}`});
movies = data.results;

const handleClick = () => {
  //this is where i'd like to update the useFetch based of on the user's search string
  //and update the data and loading property 
}
```

I want to make use of the custom hook as i know an easier way to get the job done without it. but it's important I use the useFetch()

Comment: SO is not a forum neither a chat, please restrain your familiarity and 'fluff'

Answer (score 0):

Use UseEffect to wrap your function that fetches the data

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";

const App = () =>{
const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState('morbius');
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
//fetches data when the component is first loaded
 useEffect(() => {
        fetchdata();
    }, []);

const fetchdata = () =>{
const {data, loading } = useFetch(`api-endpoint.com/apikey/${searchString}`});
movies = data.results;
}

//this is called when you click the search button
const handleClick = () => {fetchdata}

return <div>
//Input field that enables the user to enter his/her search criteria
 <input type="text" 
value={searchString}

{/*this is an onchange handler that updates the value of the searchstring when a user types*/}
onChange={e => setSearchString(e.target.value)}/>
 <button 
   onClick={handleClick}
   >Search</button>
</div>
}
export default App;
```

Comment: I get an error saying: React Hook "useFetch" is called in function "fetchData" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React hook function. React components names start with an uppercase letter. React hook names must start with the word "use"

Comment: wrap that code in a component that you need to export

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a way around it, based on the fact that at the time I posted the question I didn't have a full understanding on how useEffect works.

```
useEffect(() => {
 //fetch request here
},[url]);
```

for every the url changes it causes the useEffect to rerun which changes the component the data automatically. In other sense, i structured my code in such a way that the url variable will change when the user clicks the search button or the the enter button.

```
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
const [urlText, setUrlText] = useState('superman');

const handleClick = () => {
 setUrlText(searchText);
}
....
<input
value={searchText}
onChange=(val)=> setSearchText(val)
></input>
```